# Button Authentication redirect not working

Tags: asp.net, authentication, redirect, extjs, owin

I am implementing owin authentication for an existing webforms application.

I am trying to make my login button redirect the user to Authentication with microsoft.

This is my method in my LoginPage.aspx.cs:

```
protected void LoginClicked(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
       {
           if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
           {
               HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
               new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
               OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
           }
       }
```

This is my button in LoginPage.aspx:

```
<ext:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" MarginSpec="40 0 0 0" Text="Log in with Microsoft" Scale="Large" AnchorHorizontal="100%" IDMode="Static" Cls="loginBtn">
                                <DirectEvents>
                                    <Click OnEvent="LoginClicked">
                                    </Click>
                                </DirectEvents>
```

But when I try to click on the button, my site just refreshes and nothing happens. I also tried adding the authentication-challenge to PageLoad. This works. But the button won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I had to add `AutoPostBack="True"` as a property to my button.